# Manipulate AppData folder and fail install apps in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-installation, windows-store, appdata

I unhide AppData folder and change ownership settings and Windows fail in install/update apps from Store. [Error: 0x80070005](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOAJn.jpg)

I can't install programs from EXE MSI setup because they cant create shortcut in start menu.

And Windows Update [fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aGVw.jpg) most of times.

How to fix these changes?

Version 1903 Build 18362.267

Comment: Try [How to Repair Corrupted Windows System Files with the SFC and DISM Commands](https://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/)

Comment: @DavidPostill Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.